# Validate Data between sheets and retrive data corresponding to it using loop

Tags: excel, vba

Can anyone please help me with the Loop / Nested Loop functions.

i want to create a macro which Compares data between the sheets.

i have data in the Sheet1 under Column A (Size of row / length is not constant) which needs to Compared with the data available in the Sheet2 under Column A. If that particular cell is matching then i would require the data next to the coulmn A in Sheet1 (i.e, Column B in Sheet1) to be pasted in the column C (Sheet1). I'm trying to write a macro using the If and Loop but I fail and I forgot to save the macro what i wrote.

When I use the index match the excel becomes slow.. Also I got up a new criteria now regards to my data.. If column  A in first sheet is matched with column A in second sheet then I want the column b to be validated with that off in second sheet and if both the conditions are satisfied then I want a value in column C..

I believe this complications can be sorted with macros loop or For each Next.. I'm not sure about it..

Please sort it for me..

Can anyone pls help me with your expertise skills.

Awaiting your responses.

Many Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Still, loops might be tricky if there are a lot of lines to go through, you can though use same vlookup formula in macro to finalise afterwards:

`Sheets("first").Range("B2", Sheets("first").Range("A2").End(xlDown).Offset(0, 1)).FormulaR1C1 = "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(RC[-1],second!C1:C2,2,FALSE),"""")"
    Sheets("first").Range("B2", Sheets("first").Range("A2").End(xlDown).Offset(0, 1)).Value = Sheets("first").Range("B2", Sheets("first").Range("A2").End(xlDown).Offset(0, 1)).Value`

What that will do is: on your original "first" tab, next to all entries it will vlookup column "A" against "second" tab, and populate column "B" with any values that appear in column "B" on second tab where column "A" matches on both sheets.

Comment: Thanks for the info.. When I use ths formula or index match the excel becomes slow.. Also I got up a new criteria now regards to my data.. If column  A in first sheet is matched with column A in second sheet then I want the column b to be validated with that off in second sheet and if both the conditions are satisfied then I want an value in column C..

Answer (score 0):

Isn't it the case for a simple `VLOOKUP` formula?

Comment: Yes Ofcourse. I'm looking to automate the process. So I want it in Macro.